# Como utilizar o Atributo calc() no Pre-processador LESS

Tags: css, css3, less, preprocessador

Ao utilizar o atributo **calc()** no LESS me deparei com os seguinte problema:

Ao compilar o código `height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 6em);` o *output* resultava no calculo de 100 - 6 e adiciona a unidade do primeiro valor ao final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se resolve esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há duas soluções.

A primeira, seria retirar o **calc()** do arquivo LESS, e colocando-o diretamente no *output* CSS ou até mesmo *inline* no respectivo arquivo HTML. Isso porem gera um grande desconforto sem falar que parece um tanto gambiarra.

Já segunda solução, foi que após muita pesquisa encontrei um código de *escape* que o próprio pre-processador disponibiliza para que as contas não sejam executadas.
Ele funciona da seguinte forma: você passa **~""** e dentro das aspas vão o operador que não deve ser compilado.

Exemplo:

```
height: -webkit-calc(100vh ~"-" 6em);
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A operação passa a não ser compilado pelo LESS e calculado no navegador.

Agora sim, funcionando de maneira correta.